# How to set a snapshot file path to the current folder in MPC-HC?

Tags: video, media-player-classic

How to set a snapshot file path to the current folder in MPC-HC?
A folder there the video file is.

Also, how do I change the format of a snapshot file name to match a video file name?
My video file name is "Pipedream integration and automation.mp4"
I want a snapshot to be saved as "Pipedream integration and automation.jpg".
But instead it is saved as "Pipedream integration and automation.mp4_snapshot_00.00.981.jpg"

Thanks.